# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-calendar:20.0.0

Tags: android, kotlin, dependencies

I've been trying to get a dependency but it will not work for me. since i'm trying to get a request scope for an api like in the following:

```
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestScope(CalendarScope) // I need this CalendarScope 
        .requestIdToken(app.getString(R.string.web_client_id))
        .requestEmail()
        .build(
```

this is the implementation I'm trying to use. but its not working:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-calendar:20.4.0'
```

this is the error I get when I try to sync:

> Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-calendar:20.0.0

Comment: There is no `com.google.android.gms:play-services-calendar` in [Google's Maven repository](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.google.android.gms), and [MvnRepository's index](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=com.google.android.gms:play-services-calendar) does not seem to find it either. The only hit for that artifact name on all of Google is this page. Where did you get this artifact name? And, what documentation showed you this `CalendarScope` symbol that you are trying to reference? Perhaps we can find the right artifact from there.

Comment: I used some help from openAi due to lack of data in Kotlin. Somehow its the last part I need for my code to work and it gave that suggestion. Idk if it was removed or something

Comment: Do you have this dependency `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0'` ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for is [`CalendarScopes`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/calendar/CalendarScopes.html). The dependency can be added like so:

```
implementation "com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev20220715-2.0.0"
```

Then you should be able to use it like so:

```
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestScope(Scope(CalendarScopes.Calendar))
    .requestIdToken(app.getString(R.string.web_client_id))
    .requestEmail()
    .build(
```

**Or**
You could create the scope using [valid scope strings](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#calendar). Like so:

```
val CALENDAR_SCOPE = Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar")
```